# Insert a value into a serialized field on table1 then inserting that serialized value into table2 when there are unique constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE networks
(
    network_id SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    network_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE addresses
(
    address_id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    network_id integer REFERENCES networks (network_id),
    address    TEXT   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (address_id, network_id)
);
```

I'm trying to insert a value into `networks` and then insert the auto-generated `network_id` into another table.

This query works for values that don't exist in `networks` and does what I'm looking for:

```
WITH par_key AS (
    INSERT INTO networks (network_name) VALUES ('ethereum')
    RETURNING network_id
)
INSERT INTO addresses (network_id, address)
VALUES (
    (select par_key.network_id from par_key),
    'address1'
)
```

However, this query results in a duplicate error:

```
WITH par_key AS (
    INSERT INTO networks (network_name) VALUES ('ethereum')
    RETURNING network_id
)
INSERT INTO addresses (network_id, address)
VALUES (
    (select par_key.network_id from par_key),
    'address2'
)
```

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "networks_token_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (network_name)=(ethereum) already exists.
```

I'd like the query to execute on `addresses` with the `network_id` if the value already exists in `networks`.

Edit: had to rename `token_name` in the above table to `network_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two queries and repeat the same network with different addresses as many times as needed.

```sql
insert into networks (token_name) VALUES ('ethereum') on conflict do nothing; 

insert into addresses (network_id, address)
values 
(
 (select network_id from networks where token_name = 'ethereum'),
 'address2'
);
```

If you need a single query then use this SQL function:

```sql
create or replace function the_function(arg_token text, arg_address text) 
returns bigint language sql as
$$
 insert into networks (token_name) VALUES (arg_token) on conflict do nothing;
 insert into addresses (network_id, address)
 values
 (
  (select network_id from networks where token_name = arg_token), 
  arg_address
 ) returning network_id;
$$;
-- Use as
select the_function('ethereum', 'address1');
select the_function('ethereum', 'address2');
```

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Accept the answer?